# Set Mutable Metadata to False on SPL Token

Tags: solana-program, spl-token, solana-cli, metadata, spl

GM guys

I hope you can help me.
I'm going crazy trying to find a way to delete the "Mutable metadata" entry from my token (attached image).

Resources on the internet are limited at the moment.

I can use cli if only I could find a guide or commands to do so.

I just want
mutable = false

Notice that I have Revoked ownership and revoked freeze authority.

Thanks for the help.
[image: attached image]

Comment: i think you have to revoke update authority

Comment: Thanks. But how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use metaboss CLI to apply change on your token metadata:

metaboss set immutable --keypair 'path of config.json keypair' --account 'mint token account'

Details available at : https://metaboss.rs/set.html

Comment: Thanks fren. It work even if I recommend mint and freeze authority?